# Android waiting for listener freezing the app?

Tags: android, kotlin, listener

I want to show a progress dialog and dismiss it after the `onCompleteListener` has responded as follows:

```
class DialogSubjectsAdd: DialogFragment() {

    private val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("courses")
    private var docFetched = false
    private var processCompleted = false

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)

        getCoursesIndexDoc()
        // show progress dialog

        // wait until download operation is completed
        while (!processCompleted) {}
        // dismiss dialog

        // todo

    }

    private fun getCoursesIndexDoc() {
        // fetch the index document
        db.document("all")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    docFetched = true
                }
                processCompleted = true
            }
    }

}
```

But the above code freezes the app.

If I comment the `while` loop and dismiss dialog code as:

```
// while (!processCompleted) {}
// // dismiss dialog
```

the progress dialog shows forever.

So, why is the `while` loop freezing the app?

Even if the value of `processCompleted` never becomes `true`, I think it should result in progress bar being running forever rather than freezing the app.

But even the progress `dialog` doesn't show up because of `while` loop and the button which shows the `dialog` remains clicked and the app gets freezed, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `onCreateDialog` runs on the system's UI thread - meaning the UI can't update while something is running.

The solution is to move the code to dismiss the dialog to a separate thread - your completion listener seems like the perfect place!

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)

    getCoursesIndexDoc()
    // Don't do anything else here!
}

private fun getCoursesIndexDoc() {
    // fetch the index document
    db.document("all")
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                docFetched = true
            }
            // Instead of setting the flag, dismiss the dialog here
        }
}
```

Comment: What about the `todo` code, I think I should also move it in the listener but I have to make a `dialog` there from the data fetched and return it to the activity calling the `DialogFragment()`.

Comment: @AkshdeepSingh You wouldn't have been able to return from `onCreateDialog` anyway, returning data to the parent activity is more complicated than that. The most common way to do it is to have the Activity be a listener for your data, as explained here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#PassingEvents

Comment: I do not want to return data to parent activity, just want to return the dialog whose contents are taken from the data, so for that I need to wait but can't figure out how?